# What is this evm code produced by solc in this public array checking, and why?

Tags: evm, solc, compilation

When solc creates code for arrays when they are declared `public`. In particular, it contains a check on the length of the array. For example, this:

```
contract OutOfBoundsException {
    uint256[8] public array;
}
```

compiled with `solc --optimize` produces:

```
...
tag_3:
  pop
    /* "contracts/oobtest.sol":46:68  uint256[8] public array */
  tag_4
  calldataload(0x4)
  jump(tag_5)
tag_4:
 # dead code
tag_5:
  0x0
  dup1
  sload
  dup3
  swap1
  dup2
  lt
  tag_6
  jumpi
  invalid
tag6
 # ...
```

The `--optimize` flag was used to remove some of the crud and simplify some of the above.

What is going on in the basic block that starts `tag_5` and why is it needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: that code would be used if the contract had tried to access `array` using an accessor function. But `solc` is not smart enough to notice that that can't happen here and in many other situations like this.

Here is a situation where this check *is* needed:

```
contract PublicArray {
   uint256[8] public array;
}

contract InvalidAccess {  
    PublicArray array_contract;
    constructor() {
         array_contract = PublicArray.at(0x(...))
    }

    function go() {
       return array_contract.array[1000];
    }
}
```

This information and the above code is from the famous [Bernhard Mueller](https://thebitcoinpodcast.com/hashing-it-out-21/).

Since `array` is public, `solc` creates an accessor function for it.

`tag3` is the start of that function. `calldataload(0x4)` loads the index from calldata, then at `tag_5` there is a check that `calldataload(0x4)` < `array.length`.